Flutter: Error de version de kotlin
Intento compilar el apk de mi proyecto pero me sale el siguiente error:
Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                 │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update the  │
│ version number of the plugin with id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" in the plugins block of            │
│ F:\projects\versions\project-dos\android\settings.gradle.                                        │
│                                                                                                        │
│ Alternatively (if your project was created before Flutter 3.19), update                                │
│ F:\projects\versions\project-dos\android\build.gradle                                            │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'   

Actualmente mi version de kotlin es: 1.9.22, y mi version de gradle es: 7.1.2 Mi canal de flutter actual es Stable y mi version de flutter es 3.22.3
Este es mi build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


Debes actualizar la versión de Kotlin, que versión de Android Studio Usas?

tengo la version jellyfish 2023.3.1

Yo uso la misma versión y con kotlin_version 1.9.0 , pero en tu caso usas la última versión de Flutter  3.22.3  https://flutter-ko.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases por esto requieres una versión más actual, tal vez la última:  ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0' @CarlosPeñaranda

De acuerdo al mensaje:
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                 │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update the  │
│ version number of the plugin with id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" in the plugins block

Indica lo siguiente:
Su proyecto requiere una versión más reciente del complemento Kotlin Gradle. │
│ Encuentre la última versión en https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details y luego actualice │
│ número de versión del complemento con id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" en el bloque de complementos

En la documentación indica el problema:
Required Kotlin version
Actualiza tu versión de Kotlin, actualmente (julio 2024) la última versión es 2.0
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#kotlin-release-compatibility
Entonces cambia en tu archivo build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = 1.9.25 //*Anterior versión '1.9.22'
    ...
    ...


El mismo error te da la solución, debes actualizar tu versión de kotlin, actualmente es la 2.0.0.
En el buildScript deberás actualizar la versión de 1.9.22 a 2.0.0:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22' //cambiarlo por 2.0.0
    //....
    //....
}

